# Trouble on setting SSL certificates for Virtual Hosts using Apache\Phusion Passenger in localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to make to work HTTPS connections on *localhost*.

I am using:

- Apache v2 + Phusion Passenger
- Mac OS + Snow Leopard v10.6.6

My Ruby on Rails installation use the [Typhoeus gem](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) (it is possible to use the Ruby net\http library but the result doesn't change) to make HTTP requests over HTTPS.

I created self-signed *ca.key*, *pjtname.crt* and *pjtname.key* as [detailed on the Apple website](http://developer.apple.com/internet/serverside/modssl.html).

*Notice*: Following instruction from the Apple website, on running the `openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr` command (see the link) at this point

```
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []: (this is the important one)
```

I entered `*pjtname.com` so that is valid for all sub_domain of that site.

---

In my Apache `httpd.conf` I have two virtual hosts configured in this way:

```
# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf



# Passenger configuration
   LoadModule passenger_module /Users/<my_user_name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /Users/<my_user_name>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/passenger-3.0.2
   PassengerRuby /Users/<my_user_name>/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p136/ruby




# Go ahead and accept connections for these vhosts
# from non-SNI clients
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off


# Ensure that Apache listens on port 443
Listen 443

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443



#
# PJTNAME.COM and subdomains SETTING
#



<VirtualHost *:443>
  # Because this virtual host is defined first, it will
  # be used as the default if the hostname is not received
  # in the SSL handshake, e.g. if the browser doesn't support
  # SNI.

  ServerName pjtname.com:443
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/pjtname.com/pjtname.com/public"

  ServerAdmin you@example.com
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
  TransferLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log"

  RackEnv development

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/pjtname.com/pjtname.com/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on

  # Self Signed certificates
  # Server Certificate
  SSLCertificateFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.certificate/pjtname.crt
  # Server Private Key
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.certificate/pjtname.key
  # Server Intermediate Bundle
  SSLCertificateChainFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.certificate/ca.crt
</VirtualHost>

# HTTP Setting
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName pjtname.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/pjtname.com/pjtname.com/public"

  RackEnv development

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/pjtname.com/pjtname.com/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>




<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName users.pjtname.com:443
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/pjtname.com/users.pjtname.com/public"

  ServerAdmin you@example.com
  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
  TransferLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log"

  RackEnv development

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/pjtname.com/users.pjtname.com/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  # SSL Configuration
  SSLEngine on

  # Self Signed certificates
  # Server Certificate
  SSLCertificateFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.certificate/pjtname.crt
  # Server Private Key
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.certificate/pjtname.key
  # Server Intermediate Bundle
  SSLCertificateChainFile /private/etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.certificate/ca.crt
</VirtualHost>

# HTTP Setting
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName users.pjtname.com
  DocumentRoot "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/pjtname.com/users.pjtname.com/public"

  RackEnv development

  <Directory "/Users/<my_user_name>/Sites/pjtname.com/users.pjtname.com/public">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the `host` file I have:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost

# PJTNAME.COM SETTING

127.0.0.1 pjtname.com
127.0.0.1 users.pjtname.com
```

All seems to work properly because I have already set everything (I think correctly):

- I generated a wildcard certificate for my domains and sub-domains (in this example: *.pjtname.com)
- I have set base-named virtualhosts in the `http.conf` file listening on port `:433` and `:80`
- My browser accept certificates also if it alerts me that those aren't safe (*notice*: I must accept certificates for each domain\sub-domain; that is, [only] at the first time I access a domain or sub-domain over HTTPS I must do the same procedure for acceptance) and I can have access to pages using HTTPS

After all this work, when I make a request using Typhoeus (I can use also the Ruby Net::Http library and the result doesn't change) from the `pjtname.com` RoR application:

```
# Typhoeus request
Typhoeus::Request.get("https://users.pjtname.com/")
```

I get something like a warning about the certificate:

```
--- &id001 !ruby/object:Typhoeus::Response 
app_connect_time: 0.0
body: ""
code: 0
connect_time: 0.000625

# Here is the warning
curl_error_message: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates

curl_return_code: 60
effective_url: https://users.pjtname.com/
headers: ""
http_version: 
mock: false
name_lookup_time: 0.000513
pretransfer_time: 0.0
request: !ruby/object:Typhoeus::Request 
  after_complete: 
  auth_method: 
  body: 
  ...
```

All this means that something is wrong. So, **what I have to do to avoid the "Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates" warning and make the HTTPS request to work? Where is\are the error\errors** (I think in the Apache configuration, but where?!)**?**

P.S.: if you need some more info, let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your Apache configuration is OK, it's just that since you're using a self-signed cert, you need to specify on the client side that you're trusting the certifying authority.

It looks like Typhoeus uses curl, which has it's own certificate store, independent of OS X's Keychain (which is what would be used by your browser)

On my box, it's at /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt, and is just a concatenated list of certifying authorities. To get rid of the warning, you should be able to add your CA that you created to the end of that file:

```
cat /path/to/ca.crt >> /path/to/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

(or you can edit it manually to put it some comment about what that cert is)

However, at the next curl update, you might very well lose those changes, so it might be better to have curl simply not verify the peer's certificate. (might be good to have different prod/dev settings for that in your app). I've never used Typhoeus, but it looks like you can specify the following:

```
:disable_ssl_peer_verification => true
```

when you make calls:

```
Typhoeus::Request.get("https://mail.google.com/mail", :disable_ssl_peer_verification => true).
```

Curl has a verify_peer and a verify_host setting. If I remember well, verify_peer checks that the certificate is signed by a trusted authority, and verify_host checks that the certificate was issued to the host you're connecting to.

There's some info about using self-signed certs in the readme: https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some more "rapid" questions. 1. If I want follow your first solution, have I to set all 'SSLCertificateChainFile' values to '/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt'? 2. What means ' >>' that I should put at the end of the 'curl-ca-bundle.crt' file? 3. Can you make me a very little example on how to make prod/dev settings (mostly on how to disable\enable the 'ssl_peer_verification' in different environment settings)?

Comment: 1. You shouldn't need to change your Apache settings either way, just your app or the curl-ca-bundle.crt file on your computer. 2. the cat /path/to/ca.crt >> /path/to/curl-ca-bundle.crt command would append your certificate to the end of curl's CA bundle, but you could also just open curl-ca-bundle.crt in a text editor and copy/paste it at the end of the file. 3. To specify your rails environment, you could do something like `Typhoeus::Request.get("https://mail.google.com/mail",  :disable_ssl_peer_verification => Rails.env == "development")`

Comment: Just one more question: in a live site running in production mode, will be all those SSL\HTTPS settings less tedious than on localhost?

Comment: You only have to do all this because your certificate is self-signed. I would assume in production that you'd have a certificate that was signed by verisign, thawte or some other standard CA, in which case curl wouldn't complain. If you're not planning on paying for your cert to get signed (say for example, the server is not going to be accessed publicly), then you would probably want to add the certificate to curl-ca-bundle.crt rather than use disable_ssl_peer_verification since it could be considered a security problem.